# Pygame: Dot game using genetic algorithm

Tags: python, pygame, genetic-algorithm

I created a dot game using the library Pygame and implemented a genetic algorithm in order to create some learning effect on the dots. Basically, in each generation, the movements of the dots should evolve. But in my case, the dots don't evolve I tried to debug, but I really don't know where is the problem.

This is the main file :

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import dots
import population
import math
vec = pg.math.Vector2

############ Some color codes  ############

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255,   0)
RED = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (169, 169, 169)
TEXTCOLOR = (0,   0,  0)
###########################################

(width,height)=(800,800)
dotStartPos = (width/2, height/2)
goalPos = (int(width/2), 0)
alldotsaredead = False
running = True


# Initiliaze pygame #
pg.init()
FONT = pg.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 15)
clock = pg.time.Clock()
# Make screen and filling it with color
window = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))

# Create dots sprite group
dotssprite = pg.sprite.Group()
# goaldotsprite = pg.sprite.Group()

# Creating dots
my_population = population.Population(100,(400,700),window,1000,0)
my_dots = my_population.my_dots
[dotssprite.add(d) for d in my_dots]


# Function to update screen
def udpatescreen():
    global my_population, dotssprite
    window.fill(WHITE)
    text_count_surf = FONT.render("Gen : " + str(my_population.gen), True, BLACK)
    text_count_rect = text_count_surf.get_rect(center=(70, 30))
    window.blit(text_count_surf, text_count_rect)
    pg.draw.circle(window, RED, goalPos, 10)
    dotssprite.draw(window)
    pg.display.update()

# Function to reset screen
def resetscreen():
    global my_population, my_dots, dotssprite
    window.fill(WHITE)
    pg.draw.circle(window, RED, goalPos, 10)
    dotssprite.empty()
    my_dots = my_population.my_dots
    [dotssprite.add(d) for d in my_dots]
    dotssprite.draw(window)



# Function to update dots sprite
def rundots():
    global my_population, dotssprite
    my_population.move()
    dotssprite.update()



while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type==pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    if my_population.allDotsDead() is False:
        rundots()
    else:
        my_population.calculatefitness()
        my_population.naturalselection()
        my_population.mutatedembabies()
        resetscreen()

    udpatescreen()
```

This is the brain of each dot :

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import math

class Brain():

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size
        self.directions=[]
        self.step=0

    def randomize(self):
        for i in range(self.size):
            randomangle=random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
            self.directions.append(randomangle)

    def clone(self):
        self.brainclone = Brain(self.size)
        # print("old directions",self.directions)
        for d in self.directions:
            self.brainclone.directions.append(d)
        # print("new directions",self.brainclone.directions)    
        return self.brainclone

    def mutate(self):
        self.mutationrate = 0.01
        for i in range(len(self.directions)):
            self.rand = random.uniform(0,1)
            if self.rand < self.mutationrate:
                self.directions[i] = random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
```

This is the population of dots:

```
import pygame as pg
import dots
import random
import math

class Population():
    def __init__(self,size,startpos,window,step,id):
        self.size = size
        self.gen = 1
        self.my_dots = []
        self.id = id
        (x,y) = startpos
        for i in range(size):
            self.my_dots.append(dots.Dots((255,255,255),x,y,5,window,i,step))

    def move(self):
        for d in self.my_dots:
            d.move(random.uniform(0,2*math.pi))

    def calculatefitness(self):
        for d in self.my_dots:
            d.calculatefitness()

    def allDotsDead(self):
        for d in self.my_dots:
            if (not d.dead) and (not d.reachedgoal):
                return False
        return True 

    def naturalselection(self):
        self.newdots = []
        self.calculateFitnessSum()
        for d in self.my_dots:
            # Select parent based on fitness
            self.parent = self.selectparent()
            # Get a baby
            self.baby = self.parent.gimmebaby()
            self.newdots.append(self.baby)

        self.my_dots = self.newdots
        self.gen += 1
        self.id += 1

    def calculateFitnessSum(self):
        self.fitnesssum = 0
        for d in self.my_dots:
            self.fitnesssum += d.fitness    

    def selectparent(self):
        self.rand = random.uniform(0,self.fitnesssum)
        self.runningsum = 0
        for d in self.my_dots:
            self.runningsum += d.fitness
            if self.runningsum > self.rand:
                return d
        # Should never go to this point     
        return None

    def mutatedembabies(self):
        for d in self.my_dots:
            # print("old brain: ",d.brain.directions)
            d.brain.mutate()
            # print("new brain: ",d.brain.directions)
```

And finally here is the dot class:

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import brain
import math
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Dots(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,radius,window,id,step):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.maxspeed = 4
        self.window = window
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = vec (self.x,self.y)
        self.radius = radius
        self.step = step
        self.id = id
        self.image = pg.Surface((10,10),pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
        self.image.fill(color)
        #pg.draw.circle(self.image,(random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255)),(5,5),self.radius)
        pg.draw.ellipse(self.image,(random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255)),[0, 0, 10, 10],0)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)    
        self.accel = vec(0, 0)
        self.dead = False
        self.brain = brain.Brain(step)
        self.brain.randomize()
        self.reachedgoal = False

    def move(self,angle):
        # self.update()
        if self.dead or self.reachedgoal:
            self.rect.clamp_ip(self.window.get_rect())
        else:
            if self.vel.length() > self.maxspeed:
                self.vel.scale_to_length(self.maxspeed)
            if self.brain.step < len(self.brain.directions):
                self.accel = [math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)]
                self.step += 1
            else:
                self.dead = True
            self.vel += self.accel
            self.pos += self.vel
            self.rect.center = self.pos

    def update(self):
        if (not self.dead) and (not self.reachedgoal):
            self.move(random.uniform(0,2*math.pi))
            if self.pos.x < 0 or self.pos.x > self.window.get_width() or self.pos.y < 2 or self.pos.y > self.window.get_height():
                self.dead = True
            if self.pos.distance_to(vec((400, 0))) < 15:  # Change pos of goal if goal changed
                self.reachedgoal = True


    def calculatefitness(self):
        self.distanceTogoal = self.pos.distance_to(vec((self.window.get_width()/2), 0)) 
        self.fitness = 1/(self.distanceTogoal*self.distanceTogoal)



    def gimmebaby(self):
        self.baby = Dots((255,255,255),self.x,self.y,5,self.window,self.id,self.step) # A revoir
        self.baby.brain = self.brain.clone()
        return self.baby
```

Thanks again !!

Comment: it is long code so I can only say: use `print()` to see values in variables in different moment, and display info which part of code is executed. It can help to see how code works and what can be wrong. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: BTW: you should start with very small population so you could easily check all values.

Comment: I already executed the code with a very small population and printed all the values that help me to know where the problem is, but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: in my dot class, when i try to move each dot i use a random function that return me a random value between 0 and 2*pi, instead i should use the directions of the brain so it'll be like:

```
self.move(self.brain.directions[self.brain.step])
```

because when evolving the dots should reproduce the best movements as the dots of the past generation, and thus when i used the random angle they moving independently of the past generations.